# How to put breakpoint in class without having it's source?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I have a web application where I need to find all classes that accesses the http request object (because one of them is causing a hard to find bug). Therefore I would like to put breakpoint in some of the methods of ServletRequest implementation. This implementation is however provided by Weblogic for which I don't have sources. How can I put a breakpoint in a class anywhere in a particular method without having it's source . The Eclipse IDE is preferred.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can set a method breakpoint using the outline view of the class in question.  Then the debugger breaks at the first line of the method.

Comment: For some reason the right-click menu for the method does not contain "Toggle Method Breakpoint" on a fresh workspace, but shows up after another breakpoint was set.

Comment: Thank you so much for this one. I had been blindly stepping into each method call starting from the code that I actually had the source for, and now it works in a flash 

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your luck, you can do this with [a decompiler](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/). You'll have to place the breakpoint in the appropriate line (which, alas, might not contain "breakpointable" code)

The better way to do this is to create a `ServletResponse` wrapper. Incidentally, yesterday I created such a thing (with a slightly different purpose), so here it is:

```
public class DebugFilter implements Filter {

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {}

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) 
          throws IOException, ServletException {

        chain.doFilter(request, 
              new ResponseWrapper((HttpServletResponse) response));
    }

    public void destroy() {}
}

class ResponseWrapper extends HttpServletResponseWrapper {

    public ResponseWrapper(HttpServletResponse response) {
        super(response);
    }

    @Override
    public PrintWriter getWriter() throws IOException {
        return super.getWriter(); // breakpoint here
    }

    // Override whichever methods you like
}
```

Comment: The problem with the wrapper approach is that I already have wrapper in my application but some framework somehow operates directly on the original request - that's the bug:-).

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you will need the source code if you want this to work.

For debugging, you need readable code + line numbers that match this code.
None of these items are included in the class files

Comment: Fortunately, this isn't true. See Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen's answer!