# Setting a breakpoint in bytecode

Tags: java

As the title says: is it possible to set a breakpoint in classes with no source available? Does any debugger support this? Bonus points for being able to view the stack and local variables.

edit: Sorry for being unclear from start, but I'm not interested in method breakpoints. I want to set a breakpoint inside the method.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using eclipse, you can set breakpoints on the methods in the class using the outline view.

> You can set a method breakpoint using the outline view of the class in question. Then the debugger breaks at the first line of the method.(taken from [How to put breakpoint in class without having it's source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465918/how-to-put-breakpoint-in-class-without-having-its-source))

Right click on the method in eclipse outline view and select `Toggle Method Breakpoint`

P.S. I have tried this and it works for me.

Comment: Or in jdb `stop in package.Class.method`

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, but I'm not interested in method breakpoints.

Comment: method breakpoint sets the breakpoint at the first line of the method. You could step over to get to the line you would like to debug. 

I'll let u know if I find a way to set breakpoints at specific lines.

Comment: Can you step over bytecode instructions? I can't seem to do that in IntelliJ.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17979492/is-it-possible-to-set-breakpoints-at-a-specific-bytecode-instruction. I don't know whether this works, and I can't test right now, but the answer has been accepted, so it might be useful to you.